# How to use a single DC battery meter display for multiple 18650 cells in DIY charger

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am building an 8-cell 18650 charger using 8x TP4056 charging modules and I would like to use a single battery capacity meter to monitor the current voltage and current draw for each cell independently.

I.e. I want a toggle switch to alternate between each of the 8 battery outputs.

I've considered using a rotary switch of some kind or an Arduino, but the latter option seems unnecessarily complicated.

I'm using a battery meter similar to the one below:

https://www.banggood.com/18650-26650-Lithium-Li-ion-Battery-Tester-LCD-Meter-Voltage-Current-Capacity-p-1044589.html?akmClientCountry=AU&cur_warehouse=CN.

This works fine for a single cell battery charger but is there an analogue solution to toggle between each battery?

The circuit will be similar to the below image but without the multiple voltmeters and with a single display in their place.

[image: example circuit diagram]

Comment: Rotary switch is simple and clean, 3 pole 4 way  is ch3ap.  Make sure they are "break before make". Other approaches get complicated fast enough that TI sell a range of dedicated ICs for the purpose; e.g. the BQ2084, with a 68 page datasheet.

Comment: Note that the Reds of all displays are connected to +5v. So connect the one display Red to +5v.  Then you're only switching the Orange and Black wires to each cell.

Answer (score 2):

"radio" buttons (interlocked push buttons)

[image]

of a multi-way rotary switch. (wafer switch)
[image]